# Comparing 2 lists to remove unwanted words

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to compare a string or list to another list of unwanted words to leave only the key words behind for example:

```
>filter_words(['how', 'about', 'i', 'go', 'through', 'that', 'little', 'passage', 'to', 'the', 'south'], skip_words)
>> Expected outcome ['go', 'passage', 'south']
```

This is needs to be compared to **skip_words** which is:

```
>skip_words = ['a', 'about', 'all', 'an', 'another', 'any', 'around', 'at',
              'bad', 'beautiful', 'been', 'better', 'big', 'can', 'every', 'for',
              'from', 'good', 'have', 'her', 'here', 'hers', 'his', 'how',
              'i', 'if', 'in', 'into', 'is', 'it', 'its', 'large', 'later',
              'like', 'little', 'main', 'me', 'mine', 'more', 'my', 'now',
              'of', 'off', 'oh', 'on', 'please', 'small', 'some', 'soon',
              'that', 'the', 'then', 'this', 'those', 'through', 'till', 'to',
              'towards', 'until', 'us', 'want', 'we', 'what', 'when', 'why',
              'wish', 'with', 'would']
```

This example uses a list of words rather than a basic string so this is more a preliminary function rather than the end result but I haven't been able to find a solution as of yet.

Comment: So what have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it? SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the python documentation for list comprehension, this snippet should help:

```
newlist = []

for i in filter_words:
    if i not in skip_words:
        newlist.append(i)
```

Comment: Nope: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/3001761

Comment: All well and good linking to a meta post, but I think that in this collaborative environment it is courteous to leave a comment explaining the downvote. By all means make your downvote, but I think it helps everyone (the questioner and the answerer) if you explain why.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion, but this has been discussed multiple times on Meta (that's by no means the only discussion, see e.g. the linked questions) and repeatedly dismissed for various reasons. Downvotes are anonymous, no explanation required, and **that's not going to change**. So don't waste time asking; if people want to comment they can already, and if they don't want to they don't have to.

Comment: Well I am fairly new here, so the fact I got a downvote is fairly puzzling, I guess it is because SO isnt a code writing service so people took objection to me giving an answer. Or maybe my answer was not well explained, or maybe it was wrong. I will never know :).

Comment: My guess: Posting a code-only (first revision) answer to a broad duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, so code-only answers are frowned upon? That is not really covered in the welcome tour. Good to know for next time.

Comment: Thanks for that, I honestly just needed to know the right way of writing it. I've only been doing python for a week so I'm getting used to using the documentation relative to the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: It's possible this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307197/should-we-avoid-answering-questions-with-a-negative-score